# Is it possible to get the service name of the running service without a handle to the service key?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to get the service name of the running service without a handle to the service key, the service display name, and the service key name in c++?

Comment: You just asked basically the same question here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/11436106/903056

Comment: No, similar though, that question was with the thought that i had the service name to work with, but turns out i need to find out the service name without using the service name or service key or a handle to the key, and i was just wondering if it's even possible to do that

Comment: What do you mean by "the" service?  What service are you referring to?

Comment: We create services that run through a separate common project, and i want to get the service name of the service we are running. We have multiple services that run through the code, so it can't be hard coded in.

Comment: You could enumerate all running services and look for ones with the same process id as yourself (assuming your service is running in its own process).