# how to get Domain name of NT service in c++

Tags: c++, windows

If i start my service from service manager, it would pass just exe file name to main program. How do i get domain name of currently running NT service in Visuall c++ 6.0?
EDIT:

Let me rephrase it. I have a process which can work on different domain irrespective of user account.Let say if we use domain A to log into a machine, the process can run on domain A, domain B , domain C eTc. Is there any windows API to retrieve the domain of currently running NT service which can be used in c++.

Comment: this post may be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436106/how-do-i-get-the-service-display-name-in-c

Comment: "Domain names" are associated with user accounts. Do you perhaps mean the user account under which a service runs? Because many services run under user accoutn `SYSTEM`, which is a local name (each machine has its own unique `SYSTEM` account)